# Real-time grab the audio stream. Linux

Tags: c++, linux, audio-streaming

I have a task. Real-time grab the audio stream and process it (remove noise, adjust the frequency) and send back.

1. Which protocol is better to work for a high stream of data?
2. What libraries should I use?

Comment: Maybe you would need an RT-kernel (that's only if you want "real" realtime without big lags). To clarify about protocols and libraries you should give more info about your audio stream: speed, type, source…

Comment: Audio stream is sent to the smartphone on the network (3G). Android application is not written, so it is not clear how the server will handle siglan.